# Nested write transactions in Realm Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

When I build methods that update a realm object I always have the dilemma if it's better to put the `write`/`beginWrite` inside the method to gain atomicity and keep the callers clean, or in the caller to avoid the risk of nesting transactions.

For this reason I was thinking a way to nest transactions without risks and I made this function taking the original `write` and modifying it a bit:

```
extension Realm {
    func writeNested(_ block: (() throws -> Void)) throws {
        let isNested = isInWriteTransaction
        if !isNested { beginWrite() }
        do {
            try block()
        } catch let error {
            if isInWriteTransaction { cancelWrite() }
            throw error
        }
        if !isNested && isInWriteTransaction { try commitWrite() }
    }
}
```

Is there any downside I didn't think about?

Comment: The issue I see is not really Realm specific, but you don't know was you already in transaction or not. Basically, you don't know was data actually written or not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unaware of any downsides. I've done exactly the same myself in fact; I have a Realm helper file that has a Realm extension with code very similar to that above, but also that has extra functions for a similar purpose:

```
func addSafe<T : Object>(_ object: T)
func addSafe<T : Object>(_ objects: [T])
func deleteSafe<T : Object>(_ object: T)
func deleteSafe<T : Object>(_ objects: [T])
```

They add/delete objects, also by checking the `isInWriteTransaction` property first. I've not had any problem using them.

HTH.